# jquery on not working after adding new data with 1.7.1?

Tags: jquery

I'm currently converting my live events to use on with jquery 1.7+.

I've simply changed **live** to **on** like so:

Before:

```
$('.commentopen').live('click', function() {

    var ID = $(this).attr("id");

    $("#commentbox"+ID).slideToggle('fast');
    return false;
});
```

After:

```
$('.commentopen').on('click', function() {

    var ID = $(this).attr("id");

    $("#commentbox"+ID).slideToggle('fast');
    return false;
});
```

**on** works after a page load but fails to trigger after I add new data dynamically.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You still need to use delegation

```
$(document).on('click', '.commentopen', function() {
```

Comment: No problem. Keep in mind you'll want to replace `document` with the deepest static selector to reduce unnecessary traversal. Like, if you have a `#comments` div that's there on DOM ready, use that. `live()` bound to `document` and that's why it was slow.